# matplotlibでDataFrameを描画するときに、小数点桁数を指定する方法

Tags: python, python3, matplotlib

以下のサイトを参考に、matplotlibで、PandasのDataFrameを、画像に保存下のですが、
小数点以下の桁数をフォーマット指定することができず困っています。
小数点以下、２桁で表示する方法を教えていただけないでしょうか。

参考にしたサイト:https://tedukapm.tech/python/tableoutput/

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        {'列１': 1.25, '列２': 0.58},
        {'列１': 0.10, '列２': 0.20}  # ←ゼロ埋めして、小数点以下２桁で表示させたい。
    ],
    index=['xx', 'yy']
)
df.style.set_precision(2)
df.style.format('{:.2%}', na_rep='-')
display(df)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()  # 単位はインチ
ax.axis('off')
ax.axis('tight')

arg_map = {
    'cellText': df.values,
    'colLabels': df.columns,
    'loc': 'center',
    'bbox': [0, 0, 1, 1],
}
table = ax.table(**arg_map)
plt.savefig('image.png')
```

以下、実行結果です。
上段はdisplay(df)の結果。下段はplt.savefig(...)の結果が表示されています。
下段の２行目の値も小数点以下２桁で表示させたいです。（列ごとにフォーマット指定できればなお良しです。）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
arg_map = {
    'cellText': df.applymap('{:.2f}'.format).values,
    'colLabels': df.columns,
    'loc': 'center',
    'bbox': [0, 0, 1, 1],
}
table = ax.table(**arg_map)
plt.savefig('image.png')
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ありがとうございます。pandasのDataFrameで書式指定すること理解できました。

Answer (score 0):

「小数点以下を2桁で表示」に加え「欠損値を `-` で表示」にも対応してみました（`df_fmt` 参照）。なお，`df` を設定する形式を変えていますが表示の対応とは関係ありません。

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1.25, None],  # 0.58 -> None
                   [0.10, 0.20]],
                  index=['xx', 'yy'], columns=['col1', 'col2'])

df_fmt = df.applymap(lambda x: '-' if pd.isna(x) else f'{x:.2f}')
display(df_fmt)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis('off')
ax.axis('tight')

arg_map = {
    'cellText': df_fmt.values,
    'colLabels': df.columns,
    'loc': 'center',
    'bbox': [0, 0, 1, 1]}

table = ax.table(**arg_map)
plt.savefig('image.png')
```

また，「列毎にフォーマットを指定」にも上記を以下のように変更すれば対応できます。

```
# df_fmt = df.applymap(lambda x: '-' if pd.isna(x) else f'{x:.2f}')
df_fmt = pd.concat([
    df['col1'].apply(lambda x: '-' if pd.isna(x) else f'{x:.2f}'),
    df['col2'].apply(lambda x: '-' if pd.isna(x) else f'{x:.3f}')], axis=1)
```

[image: image.png]